# How do I add files to an existing zip archive

Tags: c#, zip

How can I add some file (almost always a single .csv file) to an existing zip file?

Comment: This question is not specific to sharpziplib, so I have reopened it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Files Into Existing Zip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091202/add-files-into-existing-zip)

Answer (score 36):

Since you are in .NET 4.5, you can use the ZipArchive (System.IO.Compression) class to achieve this. Here is the MSDN documentation: ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Here is their example, it just writes text, but you could read in a .csv file and write it out to your new file. To just copy the file in, you would use `CreateFileFromEntry`, which is an extension method for `ZipArchive`.

```
using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(@"c:\users\exampleuser\release.zip", FileMode.Open))
{
   using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
   {
       ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntry("Readme.txt");
       using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(readmeEntry.Open()))
       {
           writer.WriteLine("Information about this package.");
           writer.WriteLine("========================");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I am trying your suggestion Lord Takkera but I see a "snag". I am using the below: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Diagnostics;   The "ZipArchive" has a red underline.

Comment: The `ZipArchive` class was [added in .NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Make sure you have a project reference to System.IO.Compression, and that you are using .NET 4.5 (you should since you are on VS 2012).

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate on 'You could probably even find a way to just copy it in'? That is exactly what I need but I can't get it to work.

Comment: @MikeDymond You would use the `CreateEntryFromFile` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485720(v=vs.110).aspx If you wanted to post a new quesiton, I'd be happy to provide a code sample. I don't feel that this use case is all that important to *this* question.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks for that. I had tried that before but hadn't realised that CreateEntryFromFile is in a DIFFERENT assembly to the ZipArchive object. Once I added that reference it worked no problem.

Comment: Also, check out ZipFileExtensions.CreateEntryFromFile

Answer (score 34):

For creating, extracting, and opening zip archives, we can use [ZipFile Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx) with reference: System.IO.Compression.FileSystem. For .NET 4.5.2 and below, we also need to add reference: System.IO.Compression. Here's the method for adding files to zip:

```
    public static void AddFilesToZip(string zipPath, string[] files)
    {
        if (files == null || files.Length == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        using (var zipArchive = ZipFile.Open(zipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
                zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(fileInfo.FullName,  fileInfo.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer which I agree is much cleaner and neater.

However, I struggled a little bit at first until I realised this answer requires a reference System.IO.Compression.Filesystem (not just System.IO.Compression).

Thanks.

Comment: @FeiyuZhou, could you suggest how to add a folder and then the files.

Comment: @BinoyCherian you can modify the code in `foreach` to support folder by using `CreateEntryFromFolder` method

Comment: Don't be confused, if you don't find the `CreateEntryFromFile` at the documentation of the [ZipFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile) class. This method, and two other useful ones (`ExtractToDirectory` and `ExtractToFile`) are defined namely as extension methods in the [ZipFileExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions) class.

Comment: For something like CreateEntryFromFolder  to work we need to add Val's [extension class here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133626/creating-directories-in-a-ziparchive-c-sharp-net-4-5). It implements a `CreateEntryFromDirectory` method and work recursively just fine..

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to get DotNetZip at http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Adding files can be as easy as

```
String[] filenames = { @"ReadMe.txt",
                       @"c:\data\collection.csv" ,
                       @"c:\reports\AnnualSummary.pdf"
                     } ;
using ( ZipFile zip = new ZipFile() )
{
  zip.AddFiles(filenames);
  zip.Save("Archive.zip");
}
```

Other sorts of updates are just as trivial:

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read("ExistingArchive.zip"))
{

  // update an existing item in the zip file
  zip.UpdateItem("Portfolio.doc"); 

  // remove an item from the zip file
  zip["OldData.txt"].RemoveEntry();

  // rename an item in the zip file
  zip["Internationalization.doc"].FileName = "i18n.doc";

  // add a comment to the archive
  zip.Comment = "This zip archive was updated " + System.DateTime.ToString("G");

  zip.Save();
}
```

---

**Edited To Note:** DotNetZip used to live at Codeplex. Codeplex has been shut down. The old archive is still [available at Codeplex][1]. It looks like the code has migrated to Github:

- https://github.com/DinoChiesa/DotNetZip. Looks to be the original author's repo.
- https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd. This looks to be the currently maintained version. It's also packaged up an available via Nuget at https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/

---