# Unsubscribing from the event in delegate vs function

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Why C# allows to unsubscribe from the event when the event handler is defined as a function, but not when the event handler is defined as a delegate?

Consider the following code that works:

```
void SomeFunction()
{
  var eventRaiser = ClassRaisingEvent.GetEventRaiser();

  void handler(object sender, EventArgs ev)
  {
    ProcessData(ev);
    eventRaiser.OnEvent -= handler;
  }

  eventRaiser.OnEvent += handler
  eventRaiser.Process();
}
```

But this fails to compile at the indicated spot:

```
void SomeFunction()
{
  var eventRaiser = ClassRaisingEvent.GetEventRaiser();

  DelegateType handler = (object sender, EventArgs ev) =>
  {
    ProcessData(ev);
    eventRaiser.OnEvent -= handler; // FAILS here with "Use of unassigned local variable 'handler '"
  }

  eventRaiser.OnEvent += handler
  eventRaiser.Process();
}
```

EDIT: This question is not how to unsubscribe. This is why (in technical sense) function name is captured in the scope of the function, but the delegate's isn't.

EDIT2: Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943117/local-function-vs-lambda-c-sharp-7-0)  (and esp. pt. 2 in the answer) explains the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: jpou if the question is not about unsubscribing from events, but instead it's about unassigned local variables of type `Delegate`, you should probably present a more general example that's not related to events. Something like an `Action action = () => { action(); };`. As it stands now, I can't vote for your question to be reopened, because it looks awfully similar to the [How to remove a lambda event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362204/how-to-remove-a-lambda-event-handler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local function is defined at compile time, just like other functions. The `handler` variable, however, is only known at runtime. So, as the compiler tells you, you cannot use the `handler` variable before it's been assigned a value, which means after the closing `}` of your delegate.

What you could do to get your second snippet working, is to initialize the variable first:

```
void SomeFunction()
{
  var eventRaiser = ClassRaisingEvent.GetEventRaiser();

  DelegateType handler = null;
  handler = (object sender, EventArgs ev) =>
  {
    ProcessData(ev);
    eventRaiser.OnEvent -= handler;
  };

  eventRaiser.OnEvent += handler;
  eventRaiser.Process();
}
```

Comment: Your suggested approach also results in "Use of unassigned local variable" error.

Comment: @jpou Apart from a couple semi-colons I missed before (now fixed in the answer) I don't see the same error - [see here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F881m6).

Comment: My bad! Tested with "DelegateType handler;" instead of "DelegateType handler = null;" Your suggestion works perfectly well.