# Create a directory in a zipFile and add files using C#

Tags: c#, system.io.compression

The files I want to zip are in different folders

The folder structure is as follows:

```
FileId/FileType/File.extension
FileId/FileType/File.extension
```

I'm trying to create a zip with the following structure

```
FileType/File.extension
FileType/File.extension
```

I have tried a stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38527677/5657937) but couldn't get it to work in my scenario.

I have the files in the zip directly. But I couldn't find a good source to have the files in a specific folder.

Code I have referred from previous posts:

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(zipPath + @"\release.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Update))
        {
            ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry;
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(folderToAdd);
            FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*");
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                archive.CreateEntry(preset.FileFormat);
                readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntryFromFile(newFile, fileName);
            }
        }
```

I also tried creating a zip file in update mode and then as follows:

```
ZipFile.Open(zipPath + @"\release.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Update);
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(folderToAdd, zipPath + @"\release.zip", CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);
```

But the CreateFromDir breaks with an exception saying that the release.zip already exists.

Should I copy my files into respective folders and then apply the CreateFromDir method, or there is a better way to do this without re-copying and then CreateFromDir on top.

Comment: So you want to update zip file or create new one?

Comment: @Reniuz, Keep/Create one zip file called release.zip with the following conditions: recursively add files to the folder structure as mentioned above,  so it's gonna create one and then keep modifying until the end of files.

Comment: Why modify? Why not just zip all FileType folder? `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("FileId/FileType/", zipPath + @"\release.zip", CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);` ?

Comment: @Reniuz, FileId is a protected info so cannot do this, I already thought of this actually.

Comment: But it will create release.zip which contains folder FileType with all the files in it. There will be no /FileId folder in it